# Draw UIBezierPath following CAShapeLayer fill color

Tags: uibezierpath

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38761118/draw-lettertext-with-uibezierpath-single-line) code to create the UIBezierPath for letter and i have created the letter A like image below.

[image]

Now i want to create a UIBezierPath that follows the yellow color that is filled in CAShapeLayer like image below.

Can any one has idea how can i achieve that.

[image]

Comment: did u try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34693651/how-to-draw-line-on-image-pattern-exactly/34723668#34723668 ?

Comment: Some what similar, but i want to draw it along with UIBezierPath automatically

Comment: well: " i want to create a UIBezierPath that follows the yellow color that is filled in CAShapeLayer" , the color doesn't have a direction. you need to use the bezier path of cashapelayer anyway.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri: You are right, do you have any idea how can i use bezier path, so that i get the line with in the letter?

Comment: As suggested in my answer, you can get the shapeLayer.path, and then draw the line manually. If you want to do it automaticallyt, then you need to do little more homework, you need a alogrithm that give you the endpoint  for the letter , and then draw the bezier path that connects these end points.